# MS Access 2016: How to delete a macro?

Tags: ms-access-2016

I use Access of the Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 package. I played a little bit with the Creation of Macros. I safed a macro named "Makro1". Now I want to delete that Macro, because I don't want any garbage in the production version. How can I delete that Macro?

I tried it in the following way:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZrtv.png)

I clicked on Makro. Then the following Window appear:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3FoH.png)

In that window I can't delete Macros. I have only the option to copy them.